# WWWForm - .AddField vs .headers

Tags: unity, c#

I am using WWWForm to do the equivalent of GET and POST from python. To add headers to my unity requests, according to the documentation I could two options:

WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();

form.AddField("user", username); //***OPTION 1***: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.AddField.html

form.headers["user"] = username; //***OPTION 2***:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html

With the risk of asking a very naive question: Can someone explain the difference between the two? Thank you

Comment: Option 2 is read only so that line of code is not valid. That's what is said in the documentation.

Comment: I understand that it is a read only option, but the documentation also gives an example where it shows how to use (2) to 'add a custom header to the request' and ' post a request to an URL with our custom header'. This is why I raised the question....

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not familiar with Unity, nor with c#, this is all based on my reading the documentation. If any improvement should be made, please do so :)*

---

Let's take a look at option 2 from your question:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm (); // create a form
form.headers["user"] = username; // modify the form's headers
```

Looking at the documentation you kindly linked to out, here, `headers` is read-only. This means that the code would not compile.

The confusion you seem to ask about is: *Why do they do it in the example?*

The answer: *They're not.*

Let's take a closer look at the example, and only to the relevant lines, with my annotations:

```
// COPY the headers to a new modifiable collection
Hashtable headers = form.headers; 

// Modify the copy
headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(
    System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"));

// Use the copy
WWW www = new WWW(url, rawData, headers);
```

So the collection is not directly modified in the `form` object: it is copied to a local modifiable variable first, and it is that variable that is modified.

Perhaps they should not have named the variable `headers` like this, maybe `localHeaders` would have been a better name.

You'll notice that the `form` instance is not used after that in the example, probably because they used it to generate the basic headers and the basic data, but once they modified the custom headers, the object is probably no longer needed.

---

Now, why are there two ways to add headers? Probably for legacy reasons: maybe the option 2 (adding the headers as a hastable, and creating WWW with 3 parameters) was the first one introduced, and eventually option 1 was introduced to further simplify the process. As the documentation says, it's a helper class.

Answer (score 1):

These two do different things.

[`WWWForm.AddField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.AddField.html) adds a key/value pair of data which is part of the body of the POST request.

[`WWWForm.headers`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html), or the headers you pass to the [constructor of `WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-ctor.html), are the [HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) which are in the head of the request.

The first is application-specific data, the second are standardized instructions for proxies and web servers about how to treat the request itself. Intermediaries might mess with the HTTP headers (I've seen proxy servers which just strip any headers they don't understand), but not with the POST data.

Here is an example of a complete HTTP POST message as it goes over the wire (stolen from: http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#postmethod):

```
POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: frog@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies
```

`From`, `User-Agent`, `Content-Type` etc. are headers. `home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies` is POST data.